# MassTransit saga states receiving unexpected events

Tags: masstransit, saga, automatonymous

I am using MassTransit.Automatonymous (version 3.3.5 ) to manage a saga and I seem to be receiving unexpected events after a state has transitioned.

Here is my state set up:

```
        Initially(
            When(Requested)
                .ThenAsync(InitialiseSaga)
                .TransitionTo(Initialising)
            );

        During(Initialising,
            When(InitialisationCompleted)
                .ThenAsync(FetchTraceSetMetaData)
                .TransitionTo(FetchingTraceSetMetaData)
            );

        During(FetchingTraceSetMetaData,
            When(TraceSetMetaDataRetrieved)
                .ThenAsync(ExtractTiffFiles)
                .TransitionTo(ExtractingTiffFiles)
            );

        During(ExtractingTiffFiles,
            When(TiffFilesExtracted)
                .ThenAsync(DispatchTiffParseMessages)
                .TransitionTo(DispatchingTiffParseMessages)
            );
```

The error I *sometimes* receive is:

> The TraceSetMetaDataRetrieved event is not handled during the
>   ExtractingTiffFiles state for the ImportTraceSetDataStateMachine state
>   machine

My understanding of how this *should* work at the point of the error is as follows:

During the **FetchingTraceSetMetaData** state, at some point I'll receive a **TraceSetMetaDataRetrieved** event. When this occurs, run the **ExtractTiffFiles** method, and transition to the **ExtractingTiffFiles** state.

Once in the **ExtractingTiffFiles** state, I wouldn't expect the **TraceSetMetaDataRetrieved** event since it's what got us into the **ExtractingTiffFiles** state.

The two FetchTraceSetMetaData and ExtractTiffFiles methods are as follows (truncated for brevity):

```
    public async Task FetchTraceSetMetaData(BehaviorContext<ImportTraceSetDataSagaState, InitialisationCompleteEvent> context)
    {
        var traceSetId = context.Instance.TraceSetId;
        _log.Information($"Getting pixel indicies for trace set with id {traceSetId}");

        // Snip...!

        await context.Publish(new TraceSetMetaDataRetrievedEvent { CorrelationId = context.Data.CorrelationId });
    }


    public async Task ExtractTiffFiles(BehaviorContext<ImportTraceSetDataSagaState, TraceSetMetaDataRetrievedEvent> context)
    {
        _log.Information($"Extracting tiffs for {context.Instance.TiffZipFileKey} and trace set with id {context.Instance.TraceSetId}");

        // Snip...!

        // Dispatch an event to put the saga in the next state where we dispatch the parse messages
        await context.Publish(new TiffFilesExtractedEvent { CorrelationId = context.Data.CorrelationId });
    }
```

---

### Post posting pondering

It's just occurred to me that perhaps I should have my TransitionTo statements *before* my ThenAsync statements. e.g.

```
During(FetchingTraceSetMetaData,
        When(TraceSetMetaDataRetrieved)
            .TransitionTo(ExtractingTiffFiles)
            .ThenAsync(ExtractTiffFiles)
        );
```

Is that what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What are you using for state storage, and what isolation level are you using for transactions?

Comment: I'm using the EntityFrameworkSaga repo (backed by Postgresql) and am using IsolationLevel.Serializable. FWIW, I'm also using ec.UseInMemoryOutbox(); on the endpoint.

Comment: And I forgot to ask which transport, and how long is it taking for the consumer to complete?

Comment: The ExtractTiffFiles method can take anywhere from 200ms up to ~10 seconds. The DispatchTiffParseMessages method would be anywhere from 20ms up to ~2 seconds. Transport is RabbitMQ running from this docker: https://hub.docker.com/_/rabbitmq/ on Amazon (Redhat) Linux.

Comment: @ChrisPatterson any idea what it might be? Do you need more information?